# Liked videos for a set of users via YouTube data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For a given list of users (via their email address), I am interested in getting their most recent liked videos.

Also what is not clear is - is it possible to access any liked videos for users for which you don't have authorization?

I have seen solutions via getting the 'Liked' playlist, however it appears this can only be accessed for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a given user's list of liked videos -- of which playlist ID indeed can be retrieved via [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#list) API endpoint through the property [`contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.likes`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.likes) -- is *private data* pertaining that user.

Hence you're not going to be able to obtain from the API the kind of information you're looking for -- except if you issue an authorized API endpoint call, implying that the respective call is to be made relative to your own YouTube account (i.e. channel), in which case you'll get the ID of the playlist of videos that you liked yourself.

There's also the possibility of employing the parameter `onBehalfOfContentOwner` -- applied to each of the API endpoints `Channels.list` and [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list):

> [**onBehalfOfContentOwner**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#onBehalfOfContentOwner) (string)
>
> This parameter can only be used in a properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). Note: This parameter is intended exclusively for YouTube content partners.
>
> The `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter indicates that the request's authorization credentials identify a YouTube CMS user who is acting on behalf of the content owner specified in the parameter value. This parameter is intended for YouTube content partners that own and manage many different YouTube channels. It allows content owners to authenticate once and get access to all their video and channel data, without having to provide authentication credentials for each individual channel. The CMS account that the user authenticates with must be linked to the specified YouTube content owner.

For thorough info about these things see the document [Acting on behalf of a content owner](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/identify_content_owner), specifically the section relative to [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/identify_content_owner#YTData3).